# What should be sign of input voltage being applied to delta-sigma ADC?

Tags: adc

I am trying to understand the working of delta-sigma ADC. Here is the implementation of first order ADC.
[image]

Here is the output of voltage of each section of ADC when the input voltage is 1V.
[image]

Let me start with first row. When input is 1V and if we consider the initial capacitor voltage as 0, then i was expecting the integrator output to be -1V. However the table says +1V. So my question is are we going to consider the negative value of input sample before integrating?

Comment: This looks like a textbook solution, and your question looks like one that ought to be directed to the professor of the class.  Given that the integrator on the input is a classic inverting integrator, why would the response to a positive input **not** be negative?  Can you figure out what the circuit response will be to inputs other than +1V?  What happens when the input is 0V?  What happens when it is -1V?  Given that, do _you_ think negative inputs should be considered?